# Bring android app in foreground after receiving respose from third party app in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin

How to use moveTaskToFront while receiving some data on OnReceive method of Broadcast Receiver in Xamarin Android.

My Sample code is as below :

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.genius.pos.result" })]
public class MyBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{

 [get: Android.Runtime.Register("getTaskId", "()I", "GetGetTaskIdHandler")]
 public virtual Int32 TaskId { get; }
 public PaymentResponse paymentResponse;

 public MyBootReceiver() // public constructor
 {
 }

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String result = intent.GetStringExtra("result");
        String description = intent.GetStringExtra("description");

        if (result != null && description != Defines.POSAction.InitiateKeyedEntry.ToString())
            paymentResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentResponse>(result);

        if (description != Defines.POSAction.InitiateKeyedEntry.ToString())
        {
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
            activityManager.MoveTaskToFront(TaskId, MoveTaskFlags.WithHome);
        }
    }

    public void showResultDialog(String msg, Context context)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.SetTitle("Result").SetMessage(msg).Show();
    }
}
```

I receive a response in OnReceive method but I can't able bring my app to the foreground. I am using Intent to call third party app to do payment. The third-party app is Cayan Genius Mini.

Please help me to resolve this. I stuck in this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all do u have permission `android.permission.REORDER_TASKS`?

Also it seems that main problem in TaskID prop, can you check what  it returns?

Try to use TaskID from `MainActivity`.

Also I notice that you call your class `MyBootReceiver`, but it is not boot receiver =)

Comment: Thank you. I was not getting taskID in a proper way. I  corrected my code and get taskId from MainActivity. I have written code like as below :

        MainActivity mainActivity = ((MainActivity)Activity);
        TaskID = mainActivity.TaskId;

Comment: Glad to hear this. Could you mark this as right answer(Put a green check mark on this answer)?